# Queue blocks and execute the queue when ready

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I want to make a queue that I can add blocks to and start the processing when a propery; isReady is true. I could do this with NSOperationQueue and NSBlockOperation, but I would love to see an implementation done with ReactiveCocoa only. How can I do this?

Blocks should be excecuted in the order they are added, and it shoul be possible to add new blocks at anytime.

```
- (void)processQueueWhenReady
{
    [[[RACObserve(self, isReady) filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *isReady) {
        return [isReady boolValue];
    }] take:1] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
    }];
}

- (void)addTaskToQueue:(void (^)(void))task
{
    [operationQueue addOperation:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:task]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and I was able to achieve this using the "concat" command, concat, maintains a queue internally. So, the above can be achieved as

```
 @weakify(self);

[[[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(addTaskToQueue:)  takeUntil:objectDeallocated]
  reduceEach: ^ RACSignal *(Task * task)] {
    @strongify(self);
    return [self performTaskWhenReady:task];
 }
concat] subscribeNext: ^id(x) { }];


- (void) performTaskWhenReady : (Task *) task {
       @weakify(self);
     [[[RACObserve(self, isReady] ignore:@(NO)] take:1]
        flattenMap:^RACStream * (id *x) {
           [task execute];
        }] subscribeNext: ^ id(x) {}]
  }
```

If you want to wait on isReady just once, you can consider using skipUntil, as this also queues up the requests.

```
 [[[RACObserve(self, isReady] ignore:@(NO)] take:1] 
    skipUntilBlock: ^BOOL(id x) {
      return isReady; 
   }
   flattenMap: ^RACStream * (Task * task) {
     [task execute];
   }]
   subscribeNext: ^ id(x) 
   {}]
```

I haven't tried the above, but I think it should work.